# I like skiing rapidly

Tags: meaning, verbs, gerunds

a. I like skiing.

I think that would most likely mean

b. I like to ski.

but could be used in other contexts. Maybe I am sitting in front of the TV and am watching a ski competition and say (a) meaning I like to watch skiing.

But how about:

c. I like skiing in the Alpes.

d. I like skiing rapidly.

e. I like rapid skiing.

Does the presence of the adverbs in (c) and (d) change anything?

How about the presence of the adjective in (e)?

Many thanks.

Comment: (In English, we refer to them as the Alps.) I don't believe that (c) or (d) could be used in any context other than the speaker enjoying the personal activity of skiing. But both (a) and (e) could. Although I believe it's ungrammatical, people in my area would most likely say "I like skiing fast" for the personal activity (rather than (e)), and probably spell out "I like skiing, when it's fast" for the other (though that's still interpretable either way probably).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a. could mean that you like to do it or that you like to watch it on TV.

For the others,
c. I like skiing in the Alps.
means that you like to do it, not that you like to watch it.

"Rapidly" is unlikely in any normal speech, so I'll substitute "fast":

d. I like skiing fast.  ("fast" as an adverb)
means I like to ski, and to do it fast.

e. I like fast skiing.   ("fast" as an adjective)
could mean either that I like to ski fast, or that I like to watch skiing done fast.